# BizTalk - How is the Filter Expression of an Orchestration Receive Shape Applied

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-deployment

I'm using BizTalk 2010. I have an orchestration with an activating receive shape. This contains a filter expression against a message context property which should form part of the subscription. My problem is after deploying the application, the filter expression is missing from the subscription.

Does anyone know the process BizTalk uses to assign the filter to the subscription? As far as I can tell, it doesn't come from the binding file so I guess it must come from reflecting the orchestrations assembly?

Any ideas as to what I'm missing here would be greatly appreciated. For the time being I can manually add the filter post deployment but this is not good news for my automated build / deploy / test process!

Comment: did you promote the message context ??
the Activation property is set to True  on the firs receive shape??

Comment: +1 to counter the inexplicable downvote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, both excellent suggestions but I've been a dummy. There was a failure in my build script which meant the new orchestration assembly wasn't actually getting deployed - the previous version didn't have the filter!

Answer (score 2):

A simple test could be to create a send port with the same filter expression. If you are seeing the message flowing through the send port then there is something wrong in your orchestration filter expression. One thing to note is : filter expression on the orchestration receive port is in double quotes, where as in the send port its without the double quotes.